# prompt for opening a save dialog for excel file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio

Iam using visual studio 2012,

i would like to open "save dialog" to choose where to save my file instead of using fixed path,
the following code is a sample of what i would like to use it in:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlsWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xls As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    Dim resourcesFolder = IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\")
    Dim fileName = "book1.xlsx"

    xlsWorkBook = xls.Workbooks.Open(resourcesFolder & fileName)
    xlsWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.Sheets("a")

    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Text

    xlsWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\output\book1.xlsx")

    xlsWorkBook.Close()
    xls.Quit()


End Sub
```

i would like to change this path "C:\output\book1.xlsx" to save dialog, so i can choose where to save it manually.

thanks alot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, don't forget to dispose of com objects with the Marshal class like I added.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 Dim xls As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
 Dim xlsWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
 Dim xlsWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
 Dim resourcesFolder = IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\")
 Dim fileName = "book1.xlsx"
 xlsWorkBook = xls.Workbooks.Open(resourcesFolder & fileName)
 xlsWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.Sheets("a")
 xlsWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Text
 Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog
  If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
   xlsWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName)
   MessageBox.Show(sfd.Filename)
  End If
 End Using
 xlsWorkBook.Close()
 xls.Quit()
 Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlsWorkSheet)
 Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlsWorkBook)
 Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xls)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks alot, it's working .. I added the " Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog
  sfd.ShowDialog()
  xlsWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName)
 End Using " part only. please if you can clarify the marshal part, because i don't get it., also another simple thing, is there a way i can show a message box with the location i chose to save the file to.., thanks alot for your time

Comment: ., any suggestion regarding the message box part (show a message box with the location i chose to save the file to)., thanks

Comment: If you don't use the `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` you can find your excel still open as a process in the Task Manager.

Comment: ., thanks for your clarification, i got your point & read about it & understand it totally..thanks, but the problem is it works with me only if i close the application first, but if i kept my application running the excel process is still there, so it will be great if you any method to get rid of this.

Comment: Are you holding any instances of an Excel object anywhere - like class level?

Comment: Did you notice I rearranged the excel object to specific order - then I dispose of them reverse order.

Comment: ., yeah & i adjusted mine to be like yours, but still the same thing, it doesn't terminate until i close the application

Comment: I have no problems with this not working. There must be something else holding a reference on your excel object or wrapper class.

Comment: ., so is there any way i can discover this reference or to know what's running in the background ?

Comment: Look thru your code, are you using an alias in the imports on that form?

Comment: ., i posted my code above, please check it for any mistake or something i don't get ., thanks alot for your continuous support

Comment: .,the only thing i added is excel project reference library at the beginning of my work, so if this is the problem., how to eliminate it ?

Answer (score 1):

A little more comprehensive way to open the Save As Dialog than **OneFineDay**'s answer (using the same method).
This opens the Save As dialog using a designated directory, filename, extension type, and window title; it also prompts before overwritting any existing files.

```
Dim dir as String = "C:\output\"
Dim fName As String = "Book1"

Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog
    sfd.InitialDirectory = dir
    sfd.Title = "Save As"
    sfd.OverwritePrompt = True
    sfd.FileName = fName
    sfd.DefaultExt = ".xlsx"
    sfd.Filter = "Excel Workbook(*.xlsx)|"
    sfd.AddExtension = True
    If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        xlsWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName)
    End If
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an openfiledialog to your form and then ...

```
  With OpenFileDialog1
        .Title = " whatever"
        .InitialDirectory = "c:\"
        .Multiselect = False
        If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            xlsWorkBook.SaveAs(.FileName)
        End If
```

End With

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlsWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xls As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    Dim resourcesFolder = IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\")
    Dim fileName = "book1.xlsx"

    xlsWorkBook = xls.Workbooks.Open(resourcesFolder & fileName)
    xlsWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.Sheets("a")

    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Text

    xlsWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\output\book1.xlsx")
    xls.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlsWorkBook.Close()
    xls.Quit()


End Sub
```